# WSOD while trying to install Drupal Commerce Kickstarter

Tags: 7, installation, commerce, wsod

I'm trying to install Drupal Commerce Kickstarter with core, but I cannot go past random WSOD, or hangs, to complete installation. WSOD happens randomly, but mostly after "Configure site" step. Very rarely I can reach "Installing additional functionality", but then it just stops at some point and won't move.

(At this point: [image] )

I'm trying to install it on local apache2, and have 128M of memory_limit, 1000 of max_input_vars, and 60 of max_input_time. If you need any more information, just ask and I will provide it. What can I do to complete installation?

Comment: Any entries by watchdog (/admin/reports/dblog)?

Comment: I cannot access it because it crashes before any user is created.

Comment: I just checked database - watchdog ends with just a bunch of "%module module installed." messages . I cannot see anything fishy.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on within your apache2.conf settings file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Commerce's docs http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/troubleshooting-kickstart-2-installation

RAM: minimum 128M, more is recommended because your server can fail with this memory if it is at all strained

Since the Commerce Kickstart 2 distribution can install an entire setup and configured working demo, the installation process requires a bit more sustained power. In our early beta tests, installations can sometimes silently fail when it uses close to your memory limit.

So, the answer is, "Scotty, we need more power!"